# How can I read a QR Code from a image in flutter using a package?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am building an app using flutter where I want to scan an image(that includes QR image). I am using packages available to read QR codes, but not working for me. Is there any package/solution to read a QR code from an image?

I Tried package:

qr_code_tools: ^0.0.6`

```
Future _getPhotoByGallery() async {
     var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
 String path = image.path;
 decode(path); 
}


Future decode(String path) async {
  print(path);
  String data = await QrCodeToolsPlugin.decodeFrom(path);
  setState(() {
    _data = data;
  });
}
```

I expect the output of QRCode from the selected image of Gallery.

But getting error "Null".

Comment: you can try this one https://github.com/maja0270558/majascan_flutter

Comment: This one using camera to read the QR Image, but here I want to read it from a image selected from the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase ML Kit. They have barcode scanning, click [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes) to learn more.

Comment: I know it not the answer you want but it easier way

Answer (score 1):

You can read QR code from device gallery using this package. [qr_code_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_tools)

```
String _data = '';

  void _getQrByGallery() {
    Observable<File>.fromFuture(
            ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery))
        .flatMap((File file) {
      return Observable<String>.fromFuture(
        QrCodeToolsPlugin.decodeFrom(file.path),
      );
    }).listen((String data) {
      setState(() {
        _data = data;
      });
    }).onError((dynamic error, dynamic stackTrace) {
      setState(() {
        _data = '';
      });
    });
  }
```